# Can i access the value of the timer event in camunda?

Tags: bpmn, camunda

As I can set the duration of a timer event, can i access it through a java code? or as a camunda variable?

Comment: What exactly do you want? The value you entered in the BPMN XML (e.g. `P10D` for a timer with duration of 10 days) or the resolved timestamp at which the timer is going to be triggered?

Comment: it will be a great help if you can tell both

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to access the attribute as defined in the XML, you can use the [BPMN Model API](https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpmn-model). For example:

```
String processDefinitionId = ...
String timerEventId = ...

BpmnModelInstance bpmnModel = repositoryService.getBpmnModelInstance(processDefinitionId);
CatchEvent timerEvent = bpmnModel.getModelElementById(timerEventId);
TimerEventDefinition timerEventDefinition = 
  (TimerEventDefinition) timerEvent.getEventDefinitions().iterator().next();
TimeDuration duration = timerEventDefinition.getTimeDuration();
String configuredDuration = duration.getTextContent();
```

If you want to get the actual time at which the timer fires the next time at runtime, you'll have to query for the respective job:

```
String processDefinitionId = ...
String timerEventId = ...
String processInstanceId = ...

Job timerJob = managementService.createJobQuery()
  .processDefinitionId(processDefinitionId)
  .activityId(activityId)
  .processInstanceId(processInstanceId)
  .singleResult();
Date firingDate = timerJob.getDueDate();
```

Note that `timerJob` is null if the process instance you query for has not yet reached the timer event.